# View of Terms. How to get term synonym in Fields or via Custom field (php code)?

Tags: drupal, drupal-views

I am using Drupal 6, and Views 2.
For example, term has the alias “vocabulary/term1” (only one level, no nesting).
How do I obtain “term1” field for every item in View, displaying items of type Term?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The probably best/easiest way is to use the token of pathauto.

If you build links use the "output this field as link" feature, which converts the links to it's aliases automatically